# How to continue the next code after navigate route in angular 5?

Tags: angular

```js
        this.loading = true;
        this.subscription = this.orderService.approveOrder(this.orderDraft.orderId)
            .subscribe((result: any) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.router.navigate([`/${ODRootMenu}s/`])
                    this.successDialog(Message.TITLE_INIT_ORDER_APPROVAL_SUCCESSFULLY, Message.BODY_ORDER_APPROVAL_SUCCESSFULLY(this.orderDraft.orderId));
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            }, (error: any) => { console.log(error); });
```

After `this.router.navigate([/${ODRootMenu}s/])`, how can I wait for all the services of the new router is loaded and show *successDialog*, loading indicator?

Comment: Elaborate you question.

Comment: Sorry, you question didn't make much sense. What exactly are you trying to do here? What services do you want to wait for after navigating to `/${ODRootMenu}s/`?

Comment: `navigate` returns a `Promise`, so could always make use of that

Comment: I think you can't, using the Promise returned by navigation with `this.router.navigate([/${ODRootMenu}s/])` will execute the code you want when the route has completed the navigation, but if you have async request in `[/${ODRootMenu}s/]`, that component should show the successDialog

Comment: @GabrielLopez Any way to pass the message from the old component into new component after navigate successfully?

Answer (score 1):

`this.router.navigate` is a promise it will return true if navigation completed. You can use it like this for your example:

```
this.router.navigate([`/${ODRootMenu}s/`]).then(() =>
{
    this.successDialog(Message.TITLE_INIT_ORDER_APPROVAL_SUCCESSFULLY, 
      Message.BODY_ORDER_APPROVAL_SUCCESSFULLY(this.orderDraft.orderId));
    this.loading = false;
})
```

Comment: Your code is right. But all services in ODRoutMenu has not been called. So the dialog show and the services ( means call fetch api) has not done yet.

Comment: I think this code is fine as it is, but just move the isLoading flag to the new ODRoutMenu component, while the success dialog straight after routing is fine. Once all services have been completed, then you can set the isLoading flag to false in your router component.